# AngularJS how to add +1 to a function that returns a date

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I've a table with 5 cells in the header, each cell correspond to a week (example: week 01, week 02 and so on).

In the first cell the week is given like this:

```
<div class="monthCells">Week {{vm.selectedPeriod}}</div>
```

and the result is the text : "Week 01" in the header cell.

The code in the controller to show the week number is:

```
return moment.utc(this.date).format("WW");
```

It returns always the number of the FIRST week of the selected month,
the user can with a date picker go from month to month, and in the table it will show the weeks in that month.

What's the best way to display the other 4 weeks? 
Because I only get the number for the first week, so what do I put in the other 4 cells?

I was thinking about a counter, so it adds +1 to the number I get with:

```
return moment.utc(this.date).format("WW");
```

but the problem is, this won't be in a ng-repeat, but the table header is static, so one solution I was thinking about was put something like this in the 5 header cells:

```
{{vm.selectedPeriod}}
{{vm.selectedPeriod +1}}
{{vm.selectedPeriod +2}}
{{vm.selectedPeriod +3}}
{{vm.selectedPeriod +4}}
```

So when the user switches month, every week number will be correct but it won't work because I get  a string from my function and can't figure out how to parse it in that function with momentJS.

If someone has a solution for my idea, or if there is a better way to achieve this, please let me know

edit SOLUTION:

at the end I found a solution with only using momentJS.

```
{{vm.date | amDateFormat : 'WW'}} 
{{vm.date | amAdd : '1' : 'w' | amDateFormat : 'WW'}}
{{vm.date | amAdd : '2' : 'w' | amDateFormat : 'WW'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with a simple and smart filter like I created in this **>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txet2b1r/)**:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:0}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:1}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:2}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:3}}</div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.currentDate = moment.utc();
});

myApp.filter('dateWeekFilter', function () {
    return function (date, weeksToAdd) {
      return moment(date).add(weeksToAdd, 'w').format("WW");
    }
});
```

---

### Full solution which includes:  `selectedPeriod` scope and datepicker

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phq8vk6b/)**:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <datepicker>
    <input ng-model="datePickerDate" ng-change="dateChanged()" type="text"/>
  </datepicker>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:selectedPeriod}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:selectedPeriod+1}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:selectedPeriod+2}}</div>
  <div class="monthCells">Week {{currentDate|dateWeekFilter:selectedPeriod+3}}</div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['720kb.datepicker']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

        //Init
    $scope.currentDate = moment.utc();
    $scope.datePickerDate = $scope.currentDate.toDate();
    $scope.selectedPeriod = 0;

    //date change handling
    $scope.dateChanged = function () {
         $scope.currentDate = moment.utc($scope.datePickerDate);
    }

});

myApp.filter('dateWeekFilter', function () {
    return function (date, weeksToAdd) {
      return moment(date).add(weeksToAdd, 'w').format("WW");
    }
});
```

Comment: hey thank you for the answer, I'm trying to implement it to see if it works but I m having some issues, I'm pretty new to angularJS and I'm learning it while working on a new project, and my controller layout is a bit different, can you help me "translate" your code for my controller? I think i m using an older angularJS version.

My controller is structured like this:  
`export class TableDateController {
        static $inject: Array<string> = [
"date",`

here I declare what to inject in the controller, and below I've got:
`constructor(
            private date: number`

Comment: here I've got the constructor part, and then after this 2 and before the ''resolve'' section, I put the functions.
Sorry for the formatting but I'm having trouble formatting in this comment.

Comment: @AJ989 could you create a fiddle and let me see?

Comment: forgot to put that everything I wrote is wrapped inside this: 
`module App.Controllers {
    export interface xxxxx  extends <<<<x {
        zzzzz: string,
        date: string
    }`

Comment: ok leaving for lunch, later on I can create one if you didn't understand what I was asking,

Comment: at the end I found a solution with only using momentJS.
`{{vm.date | amDateFormat : 'WW'}}`
`{{vm.date | amAdd : '1' : 'w' | amDateFormat : 'WW'}}`
`{{vm.date | amAdd : '2' : 'w' | amDateFormat : 'WW'}}`

doing it like this works like a charm!! thank you anyway for your idea